# Insert Unicode Characters at Console Login

Tags: debian, login, console, unicode

My password contains "special" characters like `ü`. How can I login at the console (no `X` running) when the default keyboard layout does not provide these characters?

Or, differently put: how can I insert arbitrary Unicode characters at the login prompt?

My box runs Debian 6.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but how do you enter them at your X greeter (or, at all, ever)?  And if you have means to log in using the keyboard through a GUI, why is your keyboard layout for the shell different?

Comment: @trink This is my pet server project, so I don't know about Debian and X greeters. In Ubuntu, if I can't switch the keyboard layout at the login screen I press ctrl+shift+u+hex code+space. E.g., 00FC as the hex code for ü. Oh, and for the different keyboard layouts: I changed my password via ssh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem:
If the console is in Unicode mode, you can enter Unicode characters with alt+decimal unicode point. E.g., for ü: alt+252. This works for me with Debian 6 and Ubuntu 12.04.

I am not sure where it is defined whether the console should be started in Unicode mode or not. Some keywords might be kbd_mode, unicode_start and unicode_stop.

Comment: does not work for me after key map change to cz keyboard. Alt+decimal code works as I do not press alt.. I write just numbers. Someone should solve that hell.. Could not be automated as on installation time?

Comment: It seems that for some reason you have to use the numeric keypad for inserting the numbers. The 'normal' numbers don't work for me, either.

Answer (score 1):

As vonbrand told, you should never use that kind of chars in a password that you are expected to type in a *console* !
Console is the last ressort thing.

Now, to answer your question:

First, you must ensure the console is in utf-8 mode if you want to input utf-8 (otherwise, you have to ressort to input of individual bytes of utf-8 sequences, ouch!), and you need also to have a font loaded that shows those characters (for basic latin letters it shouldn't be a problem however).

You can input it 3 ways:
* if you have a mouse and gpm running you can copy and paste them (write the login greeter message so that is display all unicode chars you need)

- have the need unicode symbols available in your console keyboard (eg: "U+00FC" for lowercase "ü")
- have a dead_diaeresis (and/or any other needed dead keys) symbol in your console keyboard, and a compose file definition.
  note however that if it hasn't changed from last time, the compose file use 8bit, it is converted to unicode in an ugly way; it only works when result is in the range 0x0001 to 0x00ff (which is the case of "ü")

Note however that chances are high the right keyboard map is already there; just maybe you are loading the wrong one.

Answer (score -1):

Sort answer: Don't do that. As you see, it gives problems with keyboard differences. I also take care with the root password (sometimes needed to boot when *no* keyboard mapping is in force), so that no "impossible" characters appear.

Comment: I agree that this is a pragmatic choice, but it doesn't solve my current problem :-) But at least I'm a little bit wiser now.