# How to add unicode characters to a password?

Tags: debian, password, unicode

I am trying to have more stronger passwords, one idea of which is to add a unicode character is password. While I use something on the lines of

```
 $ apg -a 1 -M SNCL -n 3 -m 20
```

I don't know a way to add unicode characters to the mix. I do have unicode fonts and do know that unicode has had several releases. I am ok with the character set in version 1.0 itself

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Versions

This would be for generating passwords for sites where you need persistent personality/avatar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t see that it would be IMPOSSIBLE, since it is encoded to native chars in the password file. I don’t believe login supports it natively, which would be problematic

Comment: I was thinking more about website passwords rather than login to the shell but that is also a good point. Updated my query as well.

Comment: Umm.. just type them in when you set your password?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the right codepage active (UTF-8), you can do this in theory (at least in an graphical terminal), but [it's really not recommended.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66883/insert-unicode-characters-at-console-login) The problem is that you can end up trying to enter your password where the codepage doesn't contain the character that you're trying to input, which is a little bit of a problem.

It's better to follow [good password creation rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Guidelines_for_strong_passwords) (at least 12 characters, mix of uppercase, lowercase, numbers and symbols, and random) and stick with ASCII-printable characters: the extra characters provided by Unicode probably don't outweigh the issues you can face when you can't enter your password because the system doesn't allow half your password to be input!